# What is signified by Genghis Khan being born with a blood clot in his hand?

Tags: mongolian-shamanism

Genghis Khan (born Temüjin), is reputed to have been born with a blood clot in his right hand.

> Then Yisügei-ba’atur plundered Temüjin-üge, Qoribuga, and other Tatars. On his return, Lady Hö’elün was pregnant. They were at Deli’ün-boldaq on the Onon
>   when Chinggis Qahan was born. At the time of his birth, he held in his right hand a clot of blood as big as a knucklebone. Born at the time of the capture of the Tatar Temüjin-üge, they thought to name him Temüjin.
>   <sub>[The Secret History of the Mongols](https://jigjids.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/the_secret_history_of_the_mongols_the_life_and_times_of_chinggis_khan1.pdf), trans. Urgunge Onon, page 57</sub>

I've seen vague statements of this being an auspicious sign for his birth, others claiming it to be a sign of leadership, and others taking it for a sign of bloodlust.  The latter explanation I seem to see least commonly, and looks a bit like a westernized misunderstanding at first blush, but it does seem to be the interpretation taken later in The Secret History of the Mongols:

> Accidentally issuing from my hot [womb],
>   this one was born holding a black clot of blood in his
>   hand.
>   Like the qasar dog gnawing on its own afterbirth,
>   like a panther attacking on a rocky mountain,
>   like a lion unable to control its anger,
>   <sub>[The Secret History of the Mongols](https://jigjids.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/the_secret_history_of_the_mongols_the_life_and_times_of_chinggis_khan1.pdf), trans. Urgunge Onon, page 69</sub>

So, are there other sources to attest to the meaning of being born holding a blood clot?  What was the traditional meaning of it in the Mongolian traditions of the time?

Comment: Great question. I would like to see more like it: most of the questions lately have been really easy to answer, and I have a feeling that this won't be.

Comment: All I can find is various references to Mongol folklore that it signifies the child will be a great leader. Being a mostly oral tradition until the conquest of China its hard to pin down a definitive source from the Mongols themselves, only modern commentators that state this. The death and destruction does therefore seem to be a Western corruption of the true Mongol meaning.

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn - Definitely my immediate response, but it's in "the Secret History", so it's a bit harder to just dismiss.  Probably unlikely to be a *Western* corruption, at any rate.

Comment: Apparently someone wrote [an article](http://en.cnki.com.cn/Article_en/CJFDTotal-ZYMD200706011.htm) about this, I unfortunately do not have access to it.

Comment: @plannapus - Nice find.  Unfortunately I don't have access to it either (nor do I read Mandarin).  Still, the abstract is something to go on!

Answer (score 4):

In shamanic cultures a child born with something special: hair, tooth, extra toe or finger or blood clot is considered as special sign. In Hungarian mythology these children are considered as *táltos*. They are born leaders mostly in a spiritual sense. Also some children born with a blood clot or placenta covering a part of their body has a special meaning. The right hand being involved is usually a sign of leadership. (When the head is covered it means that either the child can communicate outside the our physical world or means great intellect.)